# Writing a macro that has a named symbol correctly

Tags: macros, common-lisp

The problem with the following code is multiple evaluation:

```
(defmacro with-object (name &body body)
  `(let ((,name (create-object)))
     ,@body
     (free-object ,name)))
```

but I don't know how to do this the right way.

Comment: In order to use `name` in the let binding in your code, it has to hold a symbol.
There should be no multiple evaluation problem in the code you supplied, since the symbol held by `name` is just given a binding in the expansion and evaluated for the `free-object` call within the context of that binding.

Comment: @RowPJ can it not be that ```name``` is a form that produces a symbol?

Comment: @RowPJ Oh, I guess you are right, indeed, name must be a symbol!

Comment: `dotimes` and `dolist` for example, forces the use of a symbol.

Comment: @leafbebop Ok, I see!

Comment: @RowPJ sounds like you should write that as a short answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use name in the let binding in your code, it has to hold a symbol. There should be no multiple evaluation problem in the code you supplied, since the symbol held by name is just given a binding in the expansion and evaluated for the free-object call within the context of that binding.